# Showing injective property of derivative map over vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, polynomials

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> **(1)** Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $ \leq n$. **(2)** Then
>   the derivative $D: P_n \rightarrow P_n$ is a linear map of $P_n$ into
>   itself. **(3)** Let $I$ be the identity mapping.
>
> Prove that the following linear maps are invertible:
>
> (a) $I - D^2$
>
> ...

## My observation (long):

**(1)**

I find a first sentence very interesting:

> Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $ \leq n$.

But in order for $P_n$ to be a vector space, it must contain a zero vector, which in vector space of polynomials is given by a **zero polynomial** [which has a very confusing degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1796312/513294). But it is argued that it makes most sense for zero polynomial to have $-\infty$ degree.

Hence wouldn't it be more precise to say that $P_n$ is vector space of polynomials that have a degree of $\leq -\infty$? In which case $n= -\infty$?

I don't believe $n$ is associated in any way with dimension of vector space, because in this case this assertion would break rule of cardinality.

**(2)**

> Then the derivative $D: P_n \rightarrow P_n$ is a linear map of $P_n$ into
>   itself.

This is another interesting assertion. We know that exponent property of derivative will change degree of $p_g \in P_n$ to $g-1$.

In this case, if our polynomial is something like $x^{-\infty + 1}$, we would get a derivative $\frac{d}{dx} x^{-\infty + 1} = -\infty x^{-\infty}$ which suggests that kernel is not trivial for $D$ and hence our linear derivative map over $P_n$ to $P_n$ is **not injective**... And therefore not invertible.

I definitely am wrong with this assertion, since it is assumed that $D$ is invertible over $P_n \rightarrow P_n$

**(3)**

> Let $I$ be the identity mapping.

It is very easy to prove that identity map is both injective and surjective therefore invertible. Since considering that:

$I(v) = v$

We can easily see that $Im(I) = P_n$ and $Ker(I) = {0}$.

**Polynomials being scalars**:

Considering that polynomials are scalars, isn't basis of vector space zero-dimensional? Therefore by rank-nullity theorem:

$$\textrm{dim} \, P_n = \textrm{dim} \, Im(P_n) + \textrm{dim}  \, Ker(P_n)$$

$$0 = \textrm{dim} \, Im(P_n) + \textrm{dim}  \, Ker(P_n)$$

$$0 = 0 + 0$$

Therefore by this assumption, kernel is trivial and linear map must be invertible.

---

## Question:

In this case, I'm trying to find that there exists a matrix $A$ such that:

$$(I - D^2)A = I$$

I know that identity map is invertible (as mentioned in my observation), but I'm not so sure about $D^2$. In fact I'm unable to find a matrix associated with $D$ in order to prove my assertion.

What could be the simple solution? Is my observation very incorrect?

Thank you!

Comment: $D$ is certainly not invertible. The claim is that $I - D^2$ is invertible. First, try this for just like $P_2$. What's a basis of $P_2$?

Comment: and the degree(0) = $-\infty$ thing is just a convention to make statements like deg(fg) = deg(f) + deg(g) work. You don't want to actually think of $-\infty$ as anything more than shorthand for 'something which is less than any nonnegative integer, and $-\infty + a = -\infty*a = -\infty$ for any nonnegative integer $a$'.

So in particular, 0 \in $P_n$ for any $n$ since $-\infty <n$ for any $n$ by definition.

Comment: @user113102 Well I suppose that basis for $P_2$ vector space would be in a form of a quadratic function $ax^2 + bx + c$ (wouldn't basis of such vector space have cardinality of $0$?).

Comment: Yeah, so your basis is ${1,x,x^2}$.

Comment: @user113102 I apologize for my confusion, but does that imply that basis is $\{1, x, x^2 \}$ or that there are three possible basis with cardinality of $0$? If former is true, then I guess I have to find $D=AX$ where $X= ax^2 + bx +c $ where $\{a, b, c\}$ is a coordinate vector. In which case, isn't $A \cdot (ax^2 + bx +c) = (2ax + b + 0)$?

Comment: Yep exactly. So as a matrix in terms of the basis ${x^2,x,1}, D = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\2&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @user113102 That makes sense. I guess all I have to do is to generalize this result to $n$ degree polynomials and then make calculations with it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also might be helpful to remark that, depending on what you know/are allowed to use, there are clever ways of showing that I-D^2 is invertible without explicitly finding its inverse matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invertibility of $I-D^2$ is the same as saying that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $D^2$.

Suppose $D^2p=p$. Then $p=0$, otherwise the degree of $D^2p$ is strictly less than the degree of $p$.

Technical note: the degree of the zero polynomial is usually taken to be $-\infty$ so as to preserve the properties
$$
\deg(p+q)\le\max\{\deg(p),\deg(q)\},
\qquad
\deg(pq)=\deg(p)+\deg(q)
$$
with the obvious definition $-\infty+n=-\infty$ for every $n$ (finite or $-\infty$).

---

In my lecture notes I define $P_n$ to be the vector space consisting of polynomials of degree $<n$ (so including the zero polynomial). This way $P_0$ is the trivial vector space and, in general $P_n$ has dimension $n$. But that's not really a problem with your notation. Just remember that *your* $P_n$ has dimension $n+1$ (for $n\ge0$, of course).

---

An example with $n=3$ (your notation). If we consider the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, then $D^2(1)=0$, $D^2(x)=0$, $D^2(x^2)=2$, $D^2(x^3)=6x$. Hence the matrix of $I-D^2$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the inverse is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The general formula is
$$
(I-D^2)^{-1}=I+D^2+D^4+\dots+D^{2k}
$$
where $2k\ge n$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say that but there are so many factual errors in what you wrote that I find it hard to collect them all, not even explain. This certainly is beyond what is suitable for a comment, so I will leave an answer.

**(1)**

You write:

> But in order for $P_n$ to be a vector space, it must contain a zero vector, which in vector space of polynomials is given by a zero polynomial which has a very confusing degree. But it is argued that it makes most sense for zero polynomial to have $−\infty$ degree.
>   Hence wouldn't it be more precise to say that $P_n$
>   is vector space of polynomials that have a degree of $\leq −\infty$? In which case $n=−\infty$?

What is even the problem here? If $n$ is a nonnegative integer, then $-\infty \leq n$, so by definition, $0$ polynomial is an element of any $P_n$. Remember that it's $-\infty$ and not $\infty$.

**(2)**

> This is another interesting assertion. We know that exponent property of derivative will change degree of $p_g \in P_n$ to $g-1$.

This works only for integral $g$. $-\infty$ is **not** integral. It is illdefined in this context and shoudn't be used. Rules work as long as assumptions are satisfied. Here, they aren't. So the rest of this reasoning is meaningless, :

> In this case, if our polynomial is something like $x^{-\infty + 1}$, we would get a derivative $\frac{d}{dx} x^{-\infty + 1} = -\infty x^{-\infty}$

**(3)**

> I definitely am wrong with this assertion, since it is assumed that $D$ is invertible over $P_n \rightarrow P_n$

This is false though, it is not assumed, and it is moreover false. Consider $f(x)=x^2+2$ and $g(x)=x^2-2$. Both derivatives are the same, so $D$ cannot be possibly invertible.

**(4)**

> Polynomials being scalars:

No, polynomials here are vectors. Scalars are real numbers, its coefficients.

> Considering that polynomials are scalars, isn't basis of vector space zero-dimensional?

First of all - it's not possible that the *basis* has dimension zero. The basis is just a set of vectors, for instance $\{(1, 2), (3, 4)\}$. It cannot contain zero vector, so it can't be a vector space and only vector spaces can have some dimension. But I get that you meant to say that the space itself is zero-dimensional (i.e. the basis is empty). It's still not true - the only space with empty basis is the zero space - space where the only element is zero. But there are some polynomials! So the space is non-empty.

**(5)**

> Therefore by rank-nullity theorem:
>   $$
> \dim P_n=\dim Im(P_n)+\dim Ker(P_n)
> $$

$Im$ and $Ker$ act on vector space homomorphisms. $P_n$ is a set of polynomials. What would it even mean? Kernel of a set? Image of a set? Again, this is incomprehensible and meaningless. Rank-nullity is only applicable to linear maps (vector space homomorphisms). You can't plug in anything and hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the effort to finding fundamental mistakes in the answer. I was very confused about relation between dimensionality of vector space and degree of polynomial $n$, which is obviously seen in **(1)**. For **(3)** I was thinking about linearity, e.g if $D$ is invertible then is $D \cdot D$ invertible as well? (but I forgot $I$, which was probably a main mistake). For **(4)** and **(5)** I assumed that polynomials were scalars, and I thought I could prove that kernel of vector space $P_n$ is trivial using rank-nullity.

Comment: 1. If $D$ is invertible, then $D\cdot D$ is invertible as well, but $D$ is not invertible. 2. I need to ask you again - what do you even mean by "kernel of vector space"? Give some definition please, because I feel otherwise we're not gonna get anywhere.

Comment: 1. Yes that's what I was previously thinking, I was wrong. 2. I apologize about "kernel of the vector space", I meant kernel of linear map having domain and codomain as vector space $P_n$, I was trying to find triviality of such kernel to prove injective property of derivative map over vector space of polynomials as mentioned in the question. I guess that's what K.power has displayed in the question for finite-dimensional cases.

Comment: But there are a lot of linear maps from and to $P_n$. How can you speak about all of them collectively?

Comment: Linear map that I'm currently referring to is derivative $D$, and the objective is to prove that $Ker D = \{0\}$ which as you know implies that $\textrm{dim} \, \textrm{Ker} \, D = 0$. That's why I mentioned rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: But the kernel is not trivial - nonzero polynomial $f(x) = 4$ is in the kernel.

Comment: Yes, I am now aware. I started incorrectly by trying to separately prove the injective property of $I$ and $D$, but considering that $D$ is not injective, it was obviously incorrect way to go. Correct way would be to show that kernel of $I - D^2$ is trivial. I completely agree with your answer, I'm just stating how I came up with my assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (for me at least) to prove invertibility of $I-D^2$ is to show it has a trivial kernel. This will prove that it is injective, and by the rank-nullity theorem we get surjectivity for free.

To that end fix some some polynomial $p=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$. Then
$$(I-D^2)p=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\sum_{i=2}^{n}(a_{i-2}-i(i-1)a_i)x^{i-2}.$$
Thus $(I-D^2)p=0$ if and only if $a_n=0,a_{n-1}=0$ and $a_{i-2}=i(i-1)a_i$ for all $i\in I:=\{2,\dots,n\}$. Now choosing $n\in J$ we see that $a_{n-2}=0$ (because $a_n=0$). Similarly $a_{n-3}=0$, and continuing in this manner, using "downward induction", we actually see that for those conditions to hold we require $a_i=0$ for all $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$. Thus $p\in \operatorname{ker}(I-D^2)$ if and only if $p=0$, so we can conclude that the operator is indeed injective, therefore invertible.

As enedil has pointed out, a trivial kernel only applies invertibility in finite dimensional vector spaces. In infinite dimensional vector spaces we don't have the rank-nullity theorem, so we would also have to check surjectivity of the map.

Comment: This assumes the space is finitely generated (which is true, but nonetheless worth explaining).

Comment: @enedil As the OP was is working through a Lang's linear algebra I doubted they would have been exposed to infinite dimensional vector spaces, but I have added the caveat as suggested.

Comment: @K.Power Thank you very much for the answer. Yes, i don't believe infinite dimensional vector spaces are covered in S.L Linear Algebra, at least not before Chapter 5. But I will definitely consider this for future cases.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $I - D^2$ is invertible, one doesn't actually need to compute its inverse.

**Hint** The derivative operator $D$ maps any (nonzero) polynomial to a polynomial of lesser degree, so with respect to the standard basis $(1, x, \ldots, x^n)$ the matrix representation $[D]$ of $D$ is strictly upper triangular. Thus, so is $[D]^2 = [D^2]$.

> So, $[I - D^2] = [I] - [D^2]$ is upper triangular with diagonal entries $1$, hence $\det(I - D^2) = 1$. To produce an explicit expression for $(I - D^2)^{-1}$, notice that $D^{n + 1} p = 0$ for all $p \in P_n$, so $D^{n + 1} = 0$ and thus $(D^2)^m = 0$ for $m \geq \lceil \frac{n + 1}{2} \rceil$. So, the formal series $(I - D^2)^{-1} \sim \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} (D^2)^i$ terminates; we have: $$(I - D^2)^{-1} = I + D^2 + D^4 + \cdots + D^{\lceil (n + 1) / 2 \rceil}.$$