# polynomial exercise

Tags: limits, functions, polynomials

I have the polynomial $$P(x)=(a^2-a)x^3+(a-1)x^2+(a^2-3a+2)x+a-1$$ and the function $f(a)=$ "degree of $P(x)$".

1. Find the domain of $f(a)$
2. Find the $\lim_{a\to 1}{f(a)}$ and $\lim_{a\to 0}{f(a)}$

But for $a=1$ the polynomial doesn't have a degree, so how can I find the mentioned above?

Comment: Do you have a convention for the degree of the zero polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discuss about limit at $c$, we do not need the function value at that value to exists.

Just answer the following question:

what is $\lim_{a \to 1^-} f(a)$?

what is $\lim_{a \to 1^+} f(a)$?

If they are equal, that is the answer to $\lim_{a \to 1} f(a)$

Optional interesting reading:

[The degree of zero polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/495378/306553) is usually defined to be $-\infty$.