# Minimal polynomial of zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

What is the minimal polynomial for the zero matrix ?
It cannot be $P_0(X)=0$ where $X$ is a matrix because this polynomial does not divide anything. Any polynomial of degree $0$ does not give $P_0(0)=0$ so is it a polynomial of degree $1$ ?

Are all minimal polynomials of degree $\geq 1$ ?

Comment: In my class we defined the minimal polynomial as the only monic polynomial of minimum degree such that $P(A) = 0$ (it turns out the can only be one). With this in mind the minimal polynomial of the zero matrix is $P(x) = x$.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks !

Comment: Note that every irreducible  factor of the characteristic polynomial divides the minimal polynomial. Since the characteristic polynomial of the zero matrix is $(-1)^nx^n$, then the minimal polynomial must be of the form $x^k$ for some $k\geq 1$.  The one of least degree that works is therefore $x$.

Comment: Just a note: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495378/the-degree-of-zero-polynomial and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796312/what-is-the-degree-of-the-zero-polynomial-and-why-is-it-so for a discussion of the degree of the zero polynomial - it depends on context whether you can/should call the zero polynomial a "polynomial of degree zero"